Other than impedance, what should determine the selection of R and C in a low-pass or high-pass filter?
I'm having a hard time understanding how to choose values for the resistor and capacitor in an RC low-pass or high-pass filter.  I think I understand correctly that...

The "worst-case" input impedance is roughly equal to R, so it's safe to use R as the input impedance in building the circuit.
The "worst-case" output impedance is roughly equal to R, so it's safe to use R as the output impedance in building the circuit..  this question here explains that input impedance, which we would like to be high as possible, will never be lower than R, and output impedance, which we want to be low, will never be higher than R.
I can expect attenuation of -6 dB per octave regardless of how I choose R and C, as long as the product RC is correct for the necessary time constant.
At the -3 dB point, the phase angle will be -45 degrees.

Say I needed to design a filter with a -3dB point of 5kHz.  That would require a time constant of .0000314.  That means (and I confirmed this in simulation) that any combination of RC that multiplies to equal this constant will give the needed result.  For the present, let's also assume that the driving circuit has zero source impedance and the load has infinite input impedance.  In other words, there is no concern with loading.  My filter will never affect the stage before, and it will be able to drive any load without issue.
What are the differences between setting R and C as ...

R = 1M, C = 32pF
R = 1k, C = 32nF
R = 1, C = 32uF

Put another way, what reasons other than impedance would lead one to choose specific values for R and C?

You can expect an attenuation of +6 dB per octave (not -6 dB) for a 1st order low pass filter and the opposite for a 1st order high-pass filter. I'm not sure I understand your reasoning behind using the term "worst-case".

I explained how I arrived at the impedance assumption with a link to an old SE question

@SteKulov Don't answer in the comment section

@SteKulov - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. As commented by pipe, what you kindly posted was really an answer, not a comment, Therefore I have moved & reposted it as an actual answer. || I can't repost it under your username, so I have followed a process to post it as "Community wiki" so that I don't earn any points from upvotes on it.

@SamGibson  LOLE.  Just delete it next time.  I don't consider it an answer, and would rather not have my name associated with it when considered as such.

@SteKulov - Hi, I'll bear in mind your point about deleting in future, but... (a) While comments can be deleted, if they contain useful info we try to avoid losing that knowledge (except in rare circumstances e.g. when a useful comment also breaks the CoC). (b) Anyone could have reposted your comment. The CC BY-SA license allows others to copy & repost what we write here. And related to that... (c) If someone reposts your content, they can't not give attribution, as that's required by the CC BY-SA license. || IMHO it's a useful answer, explaining the limited range of C0G cap values etc.!

Total integrated noise power! $V_n^2 = KT/C$

@SamGibson  I understand.  I guess I just don't care about "who gets credit".  My primary goal is helping people.  Since I disagree with it being a good answer I downvoted my own "answer".  I'm not trying to be difficult.  This is just my opinion.  Thank you for moderating, by the way.

If you are happy that the lowest input impedance will be equal to R and, the highest output impedance will also be equal to R then the only other thing I can think of is the scenario when the operating frequency is so high that it causes component parasitics to become significant. When this happens you may choose to reduce the capacitance so that its natural (self) resonance is above the highest frequency of interest to you.
But, in reducing the capacitance (to avoid self-resonance problems) you have to increase the resistance (to maintain the RC time constant) and, this can eventually lead to further problems. After all a resistor has parasitic capacitance and inductance.
You used the example of R = 1M, C = 32pF but, if it became 10 MΩ and 3.2 pF, the parasitic capacitance of a "standard" surface mount resistor would produce a significant error of typically around 3%.
Finally, you need to respect transmission line impedances at high frequencies and sometimes, you just cannot use simple RC filters without other measures that prevent signal reflections. This is why we use 50 Ω as the standard impedance for virtually all RF circuits and why we must employ more complex filters to maintain that 50 Ω at the section of the RF spectrum we are interested in is adhered to.

It's the components and their types, which defines things like tolerances and voltages you might want to have.
For example, choosing a 32pF capacitor means you can choose a good and highly stable Class 1 C0G/NP0 ceramic type, which could have 5% tolerance and has virtually no capacitance change due to temperature or voltage bias. However, the wires on PCB or output cables can have stray capacitance, so the filter frequency will be heavily affected by e.g. few pF of capacitance of signal wire next to ground wire.
32nF could be ceramic, but it could be a bit too large for Class 1 ceramics, so you might need to switch to worse ceramics which or more larger plastic film capacitors. The Class 2 ceramics have worse initial tolerance and they change capacitance due to temperature and voltage over them, so since your signal is AC then it will cause non-linearities to the signal.
32uF might again need a different type of capacitor with different properties. For example a basic electrolytic capacitor. They have again their own problems like initial tolerance and lifetime rating. However if your signal is AC, you might not be able to use a standard polarized electrolytic, but either a factory-made bipolar electrolytic, or build one yourself from two standard electrolytics. Size is again larger.
And even if you say you want to ignore the effect of output impedance (assumed zero) and input impedance (assumed infinite), the impedance of the filter output still matters.
If you build a real world circuit on PCB, the PCB tracks will have some capacitive and inductive coupling between them. Maybe a few picofarads, but it's still there.
So if you have a filter with 32pF capacitor, it has an impedance of 5 megaohms at 1 kHz. It means that any nearby signals or disturbance can easily couple to such high impedance output node. Compare to 32 nF having 5 kohms or 32 uF just 5 ohms.
One final note, even with ideal driver, it needs a lot of current to drive a signal through 1 ohms to 32uF. So in the event of conserving battery life or needing a smaller power supply, higher resistance is better.
When doing measurements, they also load the output. If you have a 1 Mohm 32pF RC filter, an oscilloscope input can add another 1 Mohm and 32pF to ground, loading the filter significantly. Even a 10x probe will load it down with 10Mohms and about 15pF or so. So performing measurements will have an effect.

Ste Kulov said:

In practice, you can get really nice C0G dielectric capacitors (stable across temperature and no DC bias effect) with very tight tolerances in the 10’s/100’s of pF range. I try to stay away from megaohm range resistors (whenever possible) due to noise  and loading down your measurement equipment, but you might need that range for battery powered equipment. Taking those two things into account I would probably select something like 100k & 320pF or 10k & 3.2nF or something inbetween those two endpoints.


The above was originally kindly posted as a comment, but is really an answer. Therefore, in accordance with the CC BY-SA 4.0 license and following the approach explained here, it has been moved and reposted here, unchanged and attributed, as an actual answer. The answer has been set to "Community wiki" so that I don't earn any points from upvotes on this answer, as it isn't mine. (SamGibson)


what should determine the selection of R and C in a low-pass or high-pass filter?

It depends on the application.
General factors to consider in filters are;

stored energy increases with C thus energy dissipated is independent of R

larger values may become polar so DC reversal must be avoided during power cycling and operation.

max ripple current can be a factor when using very low R values,

temperature range, tolerances vary with Arrhenius effects of 50%MTBF every 10'C rise

physical properties like ruggedness during PCB panelization, solderability, case type, size,

non-ideal electrical parameters; leakage R, ESR, Q, parasitic C, breakdown voltage  are some of the factors which may be "x" or don't care for you, but important to others.

layout requirements to avoid stray high impedance ingress for parallel traces e.g. 1pF/cm on opposite layers or 0.3 pF/cm on adjacent tracks (depends on geometry)

EMI due ingress from E or H fields increase with path length so lower impedances and a ground plane are desirable. and egress or emissions can also radiate to nearby high impedance circuits if high current pulses are applied with low R, low ESR large values with parasitic ESL ( path inductance ) may be important if long when considering > 10MHz.

considering other applications, remember that all passive conductors have some inductance and capacitance and all passive insulators have ESR and leakage R.

the most ideal capacitors are NP0/C0G ceramic where most other ceramic has a negative xxx PPM/'C tempco. and high density ceramics reduce C values towards rated DC voltage. Whereas NP0 means 0 negative or positive temperature coefficient with a  tolerance of 50 ppm/'C


Conclusion:
Your requirements are fairly low frequency and non-restrictive so ideal voltage sources with no load, you can choose any of these values but not 33 Mohm+ 1 pF due to parasitics. A 10k impedance is a common nominal value for most designs and 50 to 100 Ohms for long paths.

Available component values - especially capacitors
As previously noted by other answers, you need to select an appropriate construction and dielectric for your capacitor which makes it stable with temperature, age and vibration. This limits the maximum and minimum capacitances available.
You are also faced with the fact that capacitors have very much less range of values available, because their construction is a more involved process than resistors. 32nF or 32uF is not a standard value and would not generally be available. 33, yes; 32, no.
It is normal practise to choose a capacitor value which puts the resistor value in an acceptable range for the application. You will rarely need an exact value of capacitor in an RC circuit.
Load
If you're connecting this to an op-amp or other signal-level circuit, you probably want a fairly high impedance. Not too high - thermal noise from resistors can become a problem - but still high enough for the output to drive.
If it's in a power line, you have significant current going through it. Then you need to choose your current rating, and what the acceptable power losses are, to choose the right kind of value of resistor. Then find the closest capacitor, then work backwards to the exact resistor value.
